# Finding matrix with respect to given bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given that A:

\begin{matrix}
  a & b & c \\
  d & e & f \\
 \end{matrix}

is a matrix of T : V -> W with bases G = {g1, g2, g3} and Q = {q1, q2}, respectively.  Find the matrix of T with respect to:

(a) H = {g3, g2, g1} and R = {q1, q2}

(b)H = {g1, g2, g3} and R = {q2, q1}

Comment: Please use LaTeX. Also, do you know relevant definitions?

Comment: I thought I did but I am just confused. @Fantini

Comment: I believe there are a few typos. In $(a)$ it should probably be $H$ and $Q$ and in $(b)$ it should probably be $G$ and $R$.

Comment: No, this is how the problem is written. @user89987

Answer (score 1):

**Definition**:
$$A=\pmatrix{a&b&c\cr d&e&f\cr}$$
is the matrix of $T:V\to W$ with respect to bases $G=\{{\bf g}_1,{\bf g}_2,{\bf g}_3\}$ for $V$ and $Q=\{{\bf q}_1,{\bf q}_2\}$ for $W$ means that
$$[T({\bf v})]_Q=A\,[{\bf v}]_G$$
for all ${\bf v}\in V$, where square brackets denote coordinate vectors with respect to the specified basis.

**Hint**.  Take ${\bf v}={\bf g}_1$.  Then the definition says
$$[T({\bf g}_1)]_Q=A\pmatrix{1\cr0\cr0\cr}=\pmatrix{a\cr d\cr}\ ,$$
in other words,
$$T({\bf g}_1)=a{\bf q}_1+d{\bf q}_2\ .$$
For part (b), where ${\bf q}_1$ and ${\bf q}_2$ are given in the reverse order, this last step will need to be
$$T({\bf g}_1)=?{\bf q}_2+?{\bf q}_1\ .$$
So, what are the scalars which must replace $a,d$ (indicated by question marks in the last equation)?

Comment: I don't understand what I'm trying to obtain for the scalars a and b.  I need this done in the context of my problem… exactly.  Then, I will be able to understand it and do the others. @David

Comment: Did you successfully work out the last question in my answer?  If not, I don't think I am able to help any more.

Comment: Are they b and c? @David

Comment: No.  Just look carefully at my *second last* equation (which is known to be true) and then the solution to my last equation should be clear.

Comment: d and a? @David

Comment: Yes exactly!  So to answer (b) you need to take the original given matrix and replace $a,d$ by $d,a$, in other words, swap $a$ and $d$.  You will also need to make some other changes for similar reasons.  Can you see what the final answer will be?

Comment: what about answer (a)? This a and d swapping only applied to (b) correct?  For (b) would the other pairs also be swapped too?

Comment: That's right for (b), well done.  For (a), the vectors ${\bf q}_1$ and ${\bf q}_2$ are in their original order, so we go back to the equation $T({\bf g}_1)=a{\bf q}_1+d{\bf q}_2$.  But if you read (a) carefully you will note that now ${\bf g}_1$ is the third vector in the basis not the first.  Can you see what difference this makes to $A$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ the matrix change from the basis $G$ to the basis $H$ so we have
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
and $C$ the matrix change from the basis $R$ to the basis $Q$ then in your case $(a)$ we have
$$C=I_2$$
so the matrix of $T$ with respect to $H$ and $R$ is
$$I_2AP=AP$$
and notice that $AP$ can be obtained immediately by interchanging the columns of $A$ with respect to the permutation $(1\;3)$.

Can you now answer the case $(b)$?